# What is the best way to load data from a URL in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rake-task

I am trying to get some data from a external link with using a API key. 
I am doing this a rake task and it has to be run every 2 days during a specified time.

This is my approach.

```
desc "Run scheduled load and save sign language video clips"
task :load_and_save_sign_language_clips => :environment do
puts "Starting loading sign videos"

 def load(url)
  open(url) do |file|
    JSON.parse(file.read)
  end
 end

 for i in 0..1142
  url = "http://sampleurl.com?apikey=[key]&page=#{i}"
  clips = load(url)
  clips.each do |clip, value|
  puts clip['id']
 end
end
```

This will load approximately over 20000 data.

What will be the best way to do this kind of task ?

Comment: This way is good enough. Except for the `for`. Don't use that. Use `0.upto(1142) do |i|` instead

Comment: But if you insist on the "best", you'll have to specify, best in what? What do you want to optimize for?

Comment: you should fix your indentation. Thiss is missing an `end` for the `task` block

Comment: Sometimes I am getting an error "OpenURI::HTTPError · 500 Internal Server Error" in the log..  once I check more... It will highlight this place "open(url) do |file|"..  any advice or help ?

Comment: `500 Internal Server Error` is an error at the server. Not in your code. There isn't much you can do about that (unless the server is under your control too). You might simply ignore server errors and move on to the next or you might want to retry later.